# Prove or disprove for set $A, B, C,$ if $A \cup C = B \cup C$ and $A\setminus C = B\setminus C$, then $A=B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Prove or disprove for set $A, B, C,$ if $A \cup C = B \cup C$ and $A\setminus C = B\setminus C$, then $A=B$

Here is my attempt:
I found a counterexample
$$A = \{1,3\}$$
$$B=\{2,4\}$$
$$C = \{1,2,3,4\}$$
$$A \cup C = \{1,2,3,4\}$$
$$B \cup C = \{1,2,3,4\}$$
$$A\setminus C = \emptyset$$
$$B\setminus C = \emptyset$$
However, it is clear that $A \neq B$
Is my proof complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your counterexample suffices as a disproof.

Indeed *any* sets $A,B,C$ where $A\cap C\neq B\cap C$ and $A\setminus C = B\setminus C$ will suffice.

> Assume $A\cup C=B\cup C$.   Then any element from $A\cup C$ will also be an element from $B\cup C$, and vice versa.   If such an element is *not* an element of $C$, then it must be an element from both $A$ and $B$ — so proving that $A\setminus C=B\setminus C$.   **However,** if this *is* an element from $C$, then it *need not* be an element from either $A$ or $B$ — so we *cannot prove* that $A\cap C=B\cap C$.
>
> Consider *any* sets $A,B,C$ where $A\cap C\neq B\cap C$ and $A\setminus C= B\setminus C$, for example: $A=\{1,3\},$ $B=\{2,3\},$ $C=\{1,2\}$.   Then $A\cup C=B\cup C$, and $A\setminus C=B\setminus C$, but $A\neq B$.

---

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks fine, yes.

---

An even smaller counterexample would be $A=\emptyset$, $B=C=\{1\}$.

Then, $A\cup C = \{1\}=B\cup C$ and $A-C=\emptyset=B-C$, however $A=\emptyset\neq\{1\}=B$